# Why is appWillResignActive called when first opening app?

Tags: swift, appdelegate

When I load up the application the app delegate is calling applicationWillResignActive during the initial app load process. To my knowledge applicationWillResignActive is called when theres a phone call or text message received or when the anything interrupts the application. Heres the comment in the app delegate for appWillResignActive

> Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
>            Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

And I know this is being called when the app first opens because I logged it using NSLog and stopped it using breakpoints. This is the flow returned from me logging the function calls

1. Application Became Active
2. Application Will Resign Active
3. Application Became Active

Heres the code as written in the app delegate

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    NSLog("Application Will Resign Active")

}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    NSLog("Application BEcame Active")

}
```

I think this could be a bug since why would the app resign active when your trying to first load up the application? Or is the the correct flow for loading up the app? If so the comment makes it very confusing

P.S. I am using the simulator, could it be that this bug is only happening in the simulator?

Comment: No Ideas Anyone? Me Either

Comment: Same in real device in app installed from testflight. I've filled a radar https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4945236170113024

Comment: I think it depends on system alerts like location permission, analytics permission.